# Keras progress bar in Jupyter lab just piles up in the output cell

Tags: keras, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, tensorflow2.0, jupyter-lab

The output of Keras progress is behaving in an unexpected way. It works fine using only tensorflow/tensorflow:2.3.1-gpu-juypter docker image, but it doesn't work anymore after installing additional packages the way I did. I also tried installing packages while using a privileged user, but the issue persists. The same thing happens with Conda environment, even though I used `jupyter nbextension enable widgetsnbextension --py` and `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager`. Below is the unexpected output, Dockerfile in requirements.txt.

**EDIT:** The TQDM progress bar works as expected.

I cannot figure out why is output like this:

> Epoch 1/5   437/437 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 4.3493 - MDE: 4.3493 - MDA: 4.409 - ETA: 4s - loss: 4.0937 - MDE: 4.0937 - MDA: 4.028 - ETA: 4s - loss: 4.1436 - MDE: 4.1436 - MDA: 4.063 - ETA: 4s - loss: 4.1181 - MDE: 4.1181 - MDA: 4.054 - ETA: 4s - loss: 4.0881 - MDE: 4.0881 - MDA: 4.051 - ETA: 4s - loss: 4.0321 - MDE: 4.0321 - MDA: 3.988 - ETA: 4s - loss: 3.9547 - MDE: 3.9547 - MDA: 3.909 - ETA: 4s - loss: 3.8611 - MDE: 3.8611 - MDA: 3.812 - ETA: 4s - loss: 3.7203 - MDE: 3.7203 - MDA: 3.671 - ETA: 4s - loss: 3.4998 - MDE: 3.4998 - MDA: 3.447 - ETA: 4s - loss: 3.2848 - MDE: 3.2848 - << pile of text omited >> - MDE: 1.4330 - MDA: 1.354 - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.4304 - MDE: 1.4304 - MDA: 1.351 - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.4267 - MDE: 1.4267 - MDA: 1.347 - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.4260 - MDE: 1.4260 - MDA: 1.346 - 6s 14ms/step - loss: 1.4260 - MDE: 1.4260 - MDA: 1.3463 - val_loss: 1.0578 - val_MDE: 1.0578 - val_MDA: 1.0586 << etc. >>

Below is the Dockerfile

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.3.1-gpu-jupyter

LABEL version="2020.10.26"

ARG UID=1000 
ARG GID=1000
ARG UNAME=worker

# Suppress any manual intervention, configuring packets
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Add project to the pythonpath
ENV PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/tf

# Ubuntu 18.04 has obsolete version of NodeJS and NPM
ADD https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x nodesource_setup.sh
RUN bash nodesource_setup.sh

RUN groupadd --g ${GID} -o ${UNAME} \
    && useradd -m -u ${UID} -g ${GID} -o -s /bin/bash ${UNAME} \
    && apt-get update -q \
    #&& apt-get dist-upgrade -y -q \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nodejs \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Upgrade system pip to the latest version
RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir -U pip

# Switch to unprivileged user
USER ${UID}:${GID}
ENV PATH=$PATH:/home/${UNAME}/.local/bin

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt \
    && python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir --user SciencePlots

RUN jupyter nbextension install widgetsnbextension --py
RUN jupyter nbextension enable widgetsnbextension --py
RUN jupyter nbextension install widgetsnbextension --py --user
RUN jupyter nbextension enable widgetsnbextension --py --user

RUN jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
RUN jupyter labextension enable @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager

CMD ["bash", "-c", "source /etc/bash.bashrc && jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/tf --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser"]
```

Below is requirements.txt

```
numpy
scipy
matplotlib
pandas
h5py
jupyterlab
ipywidgets
tensorflow-gpu
tensorboard
tensorflow-probability
scikit-learn
imbalanced-learn
keras-tuner
seaborn
numexpr
joblib
```

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: The problem went away after few months. Probably some conflict between TF and jupyter-widgets extension.